# python2.7 pattern matching words

Tags: python-2.7

Python 2.7
I want to search a word that has the pattern ‘01’or ‘10’ regardless of the length of the word.
If the pattern is anything else, it is not the pattern I want:
For example:

```
10 - Yes
01 - Yes
001 - No  
10101010 – Yes
1001000 – No
11010111 – No
1010110101011 -No
```

I am looking at regular expressions.  However I only see matching for fixed length patterns given.  I want to match the whole word where the length of the word is unknown.

Comment: Why is `001` a "No"? It contains the pattern `01` in the last two digits. Are you asking for only repetitions like `01`, `0101`, `010101`, and likewise `10`, `1010`, `101010`?

Answer (score 2):

This code will find strings for which none of the characters at even positions appear at odd positions. For a 2-character alphabet of `0` and `1` (or any two characters, really), this captures those strings that are of length at least 2 and are alternating.

```
def is_alternating(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return False
    evens = string[::2]
    odds = string[1::2]
    # if the sets aren't disjoint, then at least one character appears at
    # both even and odd positions -> not an alternating string
    if set.isdisjoint(set(evens), set(odds)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

words = ['10', '01', '001', '10101010', '1001000', '11010111', '1010110101011']
results = list(map(is_alternating, words))
for thing in zip(results, words):
    print(thing)
```

Result:

```
(True, '10')
(True, '01')
(False, '001')
(True, '10101010')
(False, '1001000')
(False, '11010111')
(False, '1010110101011')
```

---

**The below solution corresponds to a different specification than what OP seems to want.**

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ['10', '01', '001', '10101010', '1001000', '11010111', '1010110101011']
>>> results = [bool(re.match('^((01)+|(10)+)$', w)) for w in words]
>>> for e in zip(results, words):
    print(e)

(True, '10')
(True, '01')
(False, '001')
(True, '10101010')
(False, '1001000')
(False, '11010111')
(False, '1010110101011')
```

I think this replicates the behavior that you want. Strings consisting strictly of one or more repetitions of either `01` or `10` (but not a mixture of those two) are matched.

Comment: because 001 does not fit the pattern 101 or 010

Comment: @user3199512 Your specification is not really very clear. What do `101` and `010` have to do with the patterns `01` and `10` that you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I only want to count patterns with this a sequence of ....010101...  any other sequence I do not want.

Comment: @user3199512 So you want any sequence in which the ones and zeros are alternating?

Comment: Minor: `if x: return True else: return False` is better written as `return x` if x is already a `bool` or `return bool(x)` otherwise.

Comment: @DSM Agreed, but I figured this would be more readable for OP.